# array.map operator returns wrong key when constructing Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a situation where I need to rearrange the object

my obj ->

```
{ '1': 2, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 1, '6': 1, '7': 2, '8': 4, '45': 1 }
```

my array ->

```
[ '2', '4', '6', '45', '1', '3', '7', '8' ]
```

what i have tried ->

```
var rearrangedObj = sortedKeys.filter((ele, ind, arr) => {
   console.log(ele, r_obj[ele])

   var q = sortedKeys[ind];
   q = ele.toString();

   var a = { q: r_obj[ele] 
   console.log(a)
   return a;
})
```

my result is ->

```
2 1
{ q: 1 }
4 1
{ q: 1 }
6 1
{ q: 1 }
45 1
{ q: 1 }
1 2
{ q: 2 }
3 2
{ q: 2 }
7 2
{ q: 2 }
8 4
{ q: 4 }
```

my expected one is -> instead of `q` the key should be the one printed in the console

```
var a1 = new Array(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 45, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8);
var r_obj = {};
var a2 = a1.map((ele, ind) => 
    if (r_obj.hasOwnProperty(ele)){
        r_obj[ele] += 1
    } else {
        r_obj[ele] = 1
    }
    return ele;
})

console.log(r_obj)

var keys = Object.keys(r_obj)

sortedKeys = keys.sort(function(a, b){
    if (r_obj[a] > r_obj[b]){
        return 1
    }
    if (r_obj[a] < r_obj[b]){
        return -1
    }
    return 0;
});

var rearr = [];
var rearrangedObj = sortedKeys.filter((ele, ind, arr) => {
   console.log(ele, r_obj[ele])

   var q = sortedKeys[ind];
   q = ele.toString();

   var a = { q: r_obj[ele] }
   console.log(a)
   return a;
})

console.log(rearrangedObj, "sortedKeys")
```

my result is ->

```
2 1
{ q: 1 }
4 1
{ q: 1 }
6 1
{ q: 1 }
45 1
{ q: 1 }
1 2
{ q: 2 }
3 2
{ q: 2 }
7 2
{ q: 2 }
8 4
{ q: 4 }
```

my expected one is -> instead of `q` the key should be the one printed in the console

Comment: `var a ={[q]:r_obj[ele]}`

Comment: Thanks, bro worked for me, am just curious , do u know the reason behind why this has happend and what mistake i have made in my code

Comment: yes ...`{q:1}` creates an object with a property named `q` with the given value, whereas `{[q]:1}` creates an object with a property whose name is determined by the value of `q`, with the given value - see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) - example: *computed property name*